# django generic view gives HTTP 405 error while generating reports and tables

Tags: python, django, class, filter

I wish to to develop a small class based view that generates reports in table form using django filters and django tables2.

I am following this guide.
http://www.craigderington.me/django-generic-listview-with-django-filters-and-django-tables2/

My code is generating the table as well filtering it but when i click on the  search button, It gives a HTTP 405 error in the terminal and displays a blank page. Here is my code. How do i fix it to make it work?

**IssueListView Class**

```
class IssueListView(PagedFilteredTableView):
    model = Issue
    template_name = 'issue_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'issue_list'
    ordering = ['id']
    table_class = IssueTable
    filter_class = IssueFilter
    formhelper_class = IssueListFormHelper

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(IssueListView,
            self).get_queryset()
        return qs

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return PagedFilteredTableView.as_view()(request)


    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(IssueListView,
            self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        search_query = self.get_queryset()
        table = IssueTable(search_query)
        RequestConfig(self.request,paginate={'per_page':30}).configure(table)
        context['table'] = table
        return context
```

**PagedFilteredTableView class**

```
class PagedFilteredTableView(SingleTableView):
    filter_class = None
    formhelper_class = None
    context_filter_name = 'filter'

    def get_queryset(self,**kwargs):
        qs = super(PagedFilteredTableView,
            self).get_queryset()
        self.filter = self.filter_class(self.request.GET,queryset=qs)
        self.filter.form.helper = self.formhelper_class()
        return self.filter.qs

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(PagedFilteredTableView,
            self).get_context_data()
        context[self.context_filter_name] = self.filter
        return context
```

**The template has the following form which contains the POST method to search the displayed table/report**

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline form-search pull-right ">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
      <input id="search_form_id" name="search" type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" placeholder="ID, Name, Account #, ZIP"{% if search %} value="{{ search }}"{% endif %}>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
    </div>              
</form>
```

Urls.py contains the following line

```
url(r'^$',views.IssueListView.as_view(),name = 'index'),
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using `post` method to retrieve results?

Comment: At a glance, I can't see how that code is meant to work. The `post` method calls `PagedFilteredTableView.as_view()(request)`, but since `PagedFilteredTableView` and `SingleTableView` (the view it inherits) do not define a `post` method, I would expect that to return a 405 (method not allowed) response

Comment: I am following this guide here. http://www.craigderington.me/django-generic-listview-with-django-filters-and-django-tables2/ and http://www.craigderington.me/generic-list-view-with-django-tables/ .. Am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I looked at the blog post you linked to, I don't see how the approach in the blogpost is meant to work.

Comment: How do i make it work? Is there any fix? Can i mixin the pagetablefiltered view with something that provides the POST method?

Comment: Why use POST? You aren't changing your database.  Try GET?  What happens then?

Comment: It might be better to ask the author of the blog post, since they know what they were trying to do. I wouldn't normally recommend calling `MyView.as_view()` within a class based view - I'd expect to call `super()` instead.

Comment: I removed everything from the template and added {% render_table table %} <form action="" method="get">
{% crispy filter.form filter.form.helper %}
<input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
</form>.. And it is now displaying a form from django filter and it filters the data correctly.  I guess this is the way to go instead of the post . But it is also showing the csrf request in the get call in the url. Is this normal?